# Where to change password?

Tags: support, login

I know this was asked before. But I really should be able to change password. I can't. There is no "change password" in my account. Or where is it?

[image]

Comment: Perhaps you should erase the email addresses (or a part of them) from the screenshot (and flag a moderator for deleting the first revision)?

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/mylogins/[your_id_number] . SITE SETTINGS > my logins

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't have a password, there's nothing to change.

By that screenshot, you're logging into your account via Google or Yahoo OAuth - neither requires a password specific for StackExchange.

Answer (score 6):

You can change your password here:

https://stackexchange.com/users/current

Go to my logins (*displaying on the left side of your profile information*) where it will show your Ids with an option to change the password.

You can change the password for a Stack Exchange account. For changing the password according to your Gmail or Yahoo id, it depends upon the password provided by them so you may have to change their respective password. Instead you can create a Stack Exchange OpenID for login.

You can register here:

https://openid.stackexchange.com/account/register

Comment: The conclusion is that I don't have an account. Only ID:s. There is no option to change password wherever I look.