# How can I update Stack Overflow login after losing control of old email address?

Tags: support

Earlier I logged in with my Gmail account (harish.bagora@hiteshi.com) and this account was belongs to my old company. I left that job and joined new company so they deactivated that account.

As of now I am already login on my machine but I'm not able to login from any another machine. If I try to login with my old Gmail account it shows **account not found**.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Where to change password?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/346663/where-to-change-password)

Comment: probably related: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/18232/how-can-one-link-merge-combine-associate-two-accounts-users-anonymous

Answer (score 5):

Go to your profile page, open the "Edit Profile & Settings" tab, select "My Logins" in the left hand side menu, and then click "add more logins" to add an email address you control.

This is described on [this page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/edit-credentials) in the help centre.

[image: "Edit Profile & Settings", "My Logins", "add more logins"]